# How to get the count of null values for each column in table

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, aggregate-functions

I have a table with 20 columns. How do I know if any of the column contains `null` values? And in case if there are `null`s ,how to get count of them?

Answer (score 8):

Use [jsonb functions:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

```
create table my_table(id int primary key, val numeric, str text, day date);
insert into my_table values
(1, 10, 'a', '2018-01-01'),
(2, 20, 'b', null),
(3, 30, null, null),
(4, null, null, null);

select key as column, count(*) as null_values
from my_table t
cross join jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(t))
where value is null
group by key;

 column | null_values 
--------+-------------
 val    |           1
 str    |           2
 day    |           3
(3 rows)
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/l_MZLgBs)

Comment: why does this not work in Looker?

Answer (score 1):

This Query should Create a query to do that:

```
SELECT 'SELECT ' || string_agg('count(' || quote_ident(attname) || ') as '||attname||'_not_null_count, count(case when ' || quote_ident(attname) || ' is null then 1 end) as '||attname||'_null_count', ', ')
    || ' FROM '   || attrelid::regclass
FROM   pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = 'myTable'::regclass --> Change myTable to your table name
AND    attnum  >= 1           -- exclude tableoid & friends (neg. attnum)
AND    attisdropped is FALSE  -- exclude deleted columns
GROUP  BY attrelid;
```

You can after that transpose columns to rows on excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can have sql query to get that details like below -

```
select 'col1Name', count(col1Name) from table where col1Name is null
union
select 'col2Name', count(col2Name) from table where col2Name is null
union ...
select 'col20Name', count(col20Name) from table where col20Name is null
```

If it is oracle, then you can write some dynamic SQL in stored procedure as well.

Comment: "If it is oracle, then you can write some dynamic SQL" PostgreSQL also supports dynamic SQL by the way.

Comment: `count(<column>)` is equal to `0`, if `<column>` is `NULL`. So your query will result in twenty rows with the column name in one columns and twenty `0`s in the other, regardless of the actual count of `NULL`s. Use `count(*)` to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

`count(nmuloc)` only counts rows where the column `nmuloc IS NOT NULL`. `count(*)` counts all rows, regardless of anything being `NULL` or not. So the difference of them is the count of rows where `nmuloc IS NULL`.

```
SELECT count(*) - count(nmuloc1) count_of_nulls_in_nmuloc1,
       ...
       count(*) - count(nmuloc20) count_of_nulls_in_nmuloc20
       FROM elbat;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see that in `all_tab_cols`, once the table is analyzed or gathered stats on that table.

```
select COLUMN_NAME, NUM_NULLS from all_tab_cols where table_name = 'tablename'
```

Comment: "`all_tab_cols`": Sounds like you're addressing Oracle, but the question is tagged Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an approximate picture of the nulls by making use of the `pg_stats` view. (See [pg_statistics docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-statistic.html) for more background).

First, you need to make sure you have up-to-date [statistics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-analyze.html) by using the `analyze` command. (If you have a lot of data or tables you may want to specify specific tables here)

Then this SQL. `null_frac` gives the % null. If you multiple by count(*) you'll get approx null records

```sql
select
    c.table_name,
    c.column_name,
    s.null_frac, 
    s.avg_width
from 
    information_schema.columns c
    inner join pg_catalog.pg_stats s
        on c.table_name = s.tablename 
        and c.column_name = s.attname 
where c.table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE';
```